# SQL Server 2005 Outer Join Problem In Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

Good Afternoon All,

I have two tables in my SQL Server 2005 DB, Main and MSDRGWEIGHTS.  I want to create a stored procedure that updates Main.RelWeight with the appropriate value from MSDRGWEIGHTS.  I have written the following code as part of the stored procedure:

```
UPDATE MAIN 
left outer join MSDRGWEIGHTS AS W ON MAIN.MSDRG=W.MSDRG
SET M.RELWEIGHT =
CASE
WHEN M.DISCHARGEDATE BETWEEN 20071001 AND 20080930 THEN W.WEIGHTSOCT07
WHEN M.DISCHARGEDATE BETWEEN 20081001 AND 20090930 THEN W.WEIGHTSOCT08
END
END
GO
```

When I execute this code, I receive error message stating incorrect syntax near keyword left.
Can anyone suggest the proper way to update RELWEIGHT using a stored procedure?  Or, is this outside the scope of a sproc?

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: What happens when you run the exact same SQL (minus the last END and the GO, of course) in SSMS?

Comment: I personnally do not like seeing queries with the word OUTER in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    UPDATE 
          m 
     SET m.RELWEIGHT= CASE
                        WHEN M.DISCHARGEDATE BETWEEN 20071001 AND 20080930 THEN W.WEIGHTSOCT07WHEN   
                       WHEN M.DISCHARGEDATE BETWEEN 20081001 AND 20090930 THEN W.WEIGHTSOCT08
    END 
    FROM 
          MAIN m 
   INNER JOIN MSDRGWEIGHTS mw 
   ON 
   mw.MSDRG = m.MSDRG
```

Comment: Note the inner join will only update those rows that actually havea value in the mw table. Really this is porbably allyou need unless you want to set an existing value to null if there is no match.